# running forloop from multi array via POST request ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Now what i want to do exactly is i received the id of the student, now i need to pass that to a php page which is below but as i am receiving the array for this followed by the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#emailIds').on('change',function(){
        var stuemID = $(this).val();
        // alert(stuemID);
         console.log(stuemID);
        if(stuemID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getDetails.php',
                data:'semid='+stuemID,
                success:function(html){
                        //alert('Done');
                    //$('#alerttrig').hide();
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert('Please choose atleast one student to view data.');
            //$('#alerttrig').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    require_once 'connectivity.php';
    //print_r ($_POST['semid']);
    //exit;
    $semid = explode(',',$_POST['semid']);
        //print_r ($semid);
        //exit;
    foreach ($semid as $emid){
        //echo $emid;
        print_r ($emid);
        exit;
        if (isset($emid) & !empty($emid)){ 
            $query="SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM test_schedule ts
                                                JOIN students s ON s.id=ts.student_id
                                                JOIN students_validity sv ON sv.student_id = s.id
                                                WHERE s.id='$emid' AND ts.exam_id != 76 AND ts.exam_id != 75 AND ts.exam_id != 83 AND ts.exam_id != 84 
                                                GROUP BY ts.student_id
                                                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                                                ORDER BY s.id ASC";
                                                print_r ($query);
                                                exit;
        $qryexec=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        //Count total number of rows
        if (mysqli_num_rows($qryexec) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryexec)){
                echo '<scrtip type="text/javascript">';
                echo 'alert('.$row['name'].')';
                echo '</script>';
            }
        }
        else{
             echo 'Something went wrong.!';
        }   
    }
    }
    ?>
```

So now i want to convert the array and make it accessible in forloop and show alert of data received via query executions

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Where specifically is this array you're talking about?  What are you trying to do with it?  What did you try and how did it not work?  What's in the `html` variable in your client-side success callback?

Comment: I have basically 2 question 
i) I want to put the values i will receive via query execution as an alert
ii) As the POST variable i have exploded , i want a forloop that will run on every id push via script
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)

Answer (score 0):

New updated answer run this file as seperate and get the flow

view file

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select multiple="multiple" name="emailIds[]" id="emailIds" tabindex="2" class="select-multiple">

                                        <option value="">Select Student</option>

                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>

                                    </select>
</body>
</html>





<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#emailIds').on('change',function(){
        var stuemID = $(this).val();
        if(stuemID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getDetails.php',
                data: { semid : stuemID },
                success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            alert('Please choose atleast one student to view data.');
            //$('#alerttrig').show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

getDetails.php

```
<?php 

    foreach($_POST['semid']  as $semval){

        // Do the code you need
            echo $semval.' ';

    }
    exit();

 ?>
```

output get alert on select and multiple select  :)

Comment: I am getting confused with this, i simply want two things two be triggered,
One is when user selects an item (or selects one by one) from drop-down my query should work 
and Secondly once the query is executed as the values he chose will show an alert with the row values executed after query run>

Comment: <select multiple="multiple" name="emailIds[]" id="emailIds" tabindex="2" class="select-multiple">
                                  <option value="Select Student" disabled>Select Student</option>
                                 <?php
                                     $get1="SELECT * FROM students";
                                     $result1 =mysqli_query($connect,$get1);
                                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                                 {
                                    extract($row1);

Comment: ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $id; ?> - <?php echo $emailId;?> - <div style="text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $name;?></div></font></option>
                             <?php
                               }
                              ?>
                              </select>

Comment: foreach ($semid as $emid){
 //echo $emid;
 print_r ($emid);
 exit;
 if (isset($emid) & !empty($emid)){ 
  $query="SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM test_schedule ts
           JOIN students s ON s.id=ts.student_id
           JOIN students_validity sv ON sv.student_id = s.id
           WHERE s.id='$emid' AND ts.exam_id != 76 AND ts.exam_id != 75 AND ts.exam_id != 83 AND ts.exam_id != 84 
           GROUP BY ts.student_id
           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
           ORDER BY s.id ASC";
           print_r ($query);
           exit;
 $qryexec=mysqli_query($connect,$query);

Comment: i still not achieved what i was looking for it only triggers the first value not even moving to second one.

Comment: I simply want to run a for loop for this 
foreach($semid  as $semval){
  echo $value."<br />";
basing upon the values received from here
$('#emailIds').on('change',function(){
        var stuemID = $(this).val();
         //alert(stuemID);
         console.log(stuemID);
        if(stuemID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'getDetails.php',
                data:'semid='+stuemID,
                success:function(html)

Comment: Update your question with html

Comment: yeah sure , i simply want on every select the relevant data must show as an basic javascript alert, that's all.

Comment: Updated my answer please check :)

Comment: Well it worked, but i want a small change i want to get the current id on each select but it is still showing 1 even if it is 2, and i want to pass single to my post url not in array or in implode form.